# How to test a search page that has more than 20 fields

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am quite new to **selenium web driver** i have a search page that has more than 20 fields.
I had created an **excel file** that contains all the data that i want to pass it through my test.My excel file will contain **20 rows** and and for each row there will be **20 columns** as well.
So my question can i use data provider to do something like that or i just need to create 20 test methods and for every method i should read a row? Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want to achieve? just want to pass search term one by one from excel to your site search field?

Comment: @HelpingHands I want to pass the row so i need it save all the row in array of lists then i will pass the list into the data provider

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the Apache POI library to accomplish this.

Sample code for Apache POI:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xlsx"));                 
//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (file);     
//Get first sheet from the workbook
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);  
Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
String data = row.getCell(columnindex).getStringCellValue();
```

**DataProvider**:
The @DataProvider marks a method as supplying data for a test method. The annotated method must return an Object[][].  The @Test method that wants to receive data from this DataProvider needs to use a dataProvider name equals to the name of this annotation.

**Attributes**:

1. name - The name of the data provider. If it's not supplied, the name of this data provider will automatically be set to the name of the method.
2. parallel - If set to true, tests generated using this data provider are run in parallel. Default value is false.

Tutorial for @Dataprovider: http://seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/dataprovider-in-testng

Sample code for Dataprovider:

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DataProviderExample{

    //This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
    // "getdata" is the function name which is passing the data
       // Number of columns should match the number of input parameters
    @Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public void setData(String username, String password)
    {
        System.out.println("you have provided username as::"+username);
        System.out.println("you have provided password as::"+password);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData()
    {
    //Rows - Number of times your test has to be repeated.
    //Columns - Number of parameters in test data.
    Object[][] data = new Object[3][2];

    // 1st row
    data[0][0] ="sampleuser1";
    data[0][1] = "abcdef";

    // 2nd row
    data[1][0] ="testuser2";
    data[1][1] = "zxcvb";

    // 3rd row
    data[2][0] ="guestuser3";
    data[2][1] = "pass123";

    return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could explain a little bit more about how DataProviders support data-driven testing in TestNG.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem because I want to pass all the data in the row so i need it save all the row in array of lists then i will pass the list into the data provider but the data provider doesn't read a list

Comment: You could do the following (without using Dataprovider): 1. Use Apache POI to read the cell values 2. Store these values in your ArrayList 3. Call the function to return your ArrayList